# NSView Flickering on window resizing

Tags: objective-c, nswindow, flicker, chromium-embedded, window-resize

I've implemented a resizing method for cef3's NSWindow:

```
void ClientHandler::setWindowRect(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
{
    if(!CefCurrentlyOn(TID_UI))
    {
       // Execute on the UI thread.
       CefPostTask(TID_UI,
                base::Bind(&ClientHandler::setWindowRect, this, left, top, right, bottom));
       return;
    }
    NSView* view = (NSView*) GetBrowser()->GetHost()->GetWindowHandle();
    NSWindow* window = [view window];

    NSRect winRect = NSMakeRect(left, top, right - left, bottom - top);
    [window setFrame:winRect display:NO];

}
```

I'm calling this method frequently and it causes the cef window to flicker.
Any ideas will be appreciated. Thanks!